# SQL command not properly ended in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

i have a servlet which takes emailid and password from a form, which is then supposed to access the table called hr.faculty, and if the credentials found correct, creates a session. but i am getting an error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` when i try to login. plz help.

The code is as follows:

```
email=request.getParameter("email");
pass=request.getParameter("pass");       
try{
try {
Class.forName(driver);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
out.println(ex);
}
Connection con=null;
con=DriverManager.getConnection(oracleURL,username,password);
DatabaseMetaData dmd=con.getMetaData();
Statement s=con.createStatement();
String q="SELECT password FROM HR.faculty WHERE email=" + email;
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(q);
pw=rs.getString("password");
if(pw.equals(pass)){
//session creation   
}
```

Comment: Should I even mention the fact that this allows sql-injection?

Comment: Use proper bound parameters instead of literal appends.  BAD!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a syntax error on your query, you're not using binding variables so you have to do the wrapping yourself. This would work:

```
String q="SELECT password FROM HR.faculty WHERE email='" + email+"'";
```

In general using prepared statements is much preferred as it protects you from SQL injection.

Also looks like your retrieval of the result is invalid, you need to move the cursor in the `ResultSet` otherwise it will return an error. This would work:

```
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(q);
rs.first();//move to the first result
pw=rs.getString("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`String q="SELECT password FROM HR.faculty WHERE email='" + email + "'";`

But you look for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of cringe every time I see code like this. You should be using prepared Statements instead. What you are doing allows [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection).

It will alleviate the security holes, and your syntax error if you use prepared statements.

Use `PreparedStatment s = con.prepareStatement(mySqlQuery);` instead of `Statement s = con.createStatement();`

Then in your sql string, you replace all "input" with a ?, so `mySqlQuey = "SELECT password FROM HR.faculty WHERE email=?"`

You then replace all question marks with `s.setString(1, value)`. Or if you were replacing it with an int it would be `s.setInt(1, value);` etc.

The edit to your code:

```
Connection con=null;
con=DriverManager.getConnection(oracleURL,username,password);
DatabaseMetaData dmd=con.getMetaData();
PreparedStatement s=con.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM HR.faculty WHERE email=?");
s.setString(1, email);
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(q);
pw=rs.getString("password");
if(pw.equals(pass)){
//session creation   
}
```